# Cryptography / Compression in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, encryption, compression, rsa

I'm porting my application from WPF to Silverlight. The biggest problem is that my application uses RSA encryption and Deflate compression, and both classes are not available in Silverlight.

I know that you can view the sourcecode of any .NET class using reflection, so would it be possible to just 'decompile' the RSACryptoService class, and re-use that code for Silverlight (provided the algoritm doesn't use any classes that are missing in SL)?

Or what would be the best solution? I know I can write my own RSA/Deflate algoritms, but it seems to make sense to re-use the source of the WPF classes when possible.

Comment: I think most crypto classes in .net are just wrappers over native crypto libraries. And even if it worked it probably wouldn't be legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA in Silverlight:
http://scrypt.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) has compression streams, and I think they are even binary compatible with the built in deflate stream.